# Approximation for set cover

Tags: algorithm, approximation

I started learning about approximation algorithms,
I'm reading a book about that and I don't understand the analysis for the set cover algorithm.

Can someone please explain lemma 2.3 ? 
it's short but I don't understand it...

http://view.samurajdata.se/psview.php?id=0482e9ff&page=13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is assigning a "price" `price(e)` to each element of the universe `U` where that price is the cost of the set `S` used to cover `e` divided by the number of elements newly covered by the set `S` (any elements already covered must have been assigned a lower price by a previous set due to the definition of the algorithm).

There exists an optimal solution which chooses a set of sets with total cost `OPT`. As that solution covers all elements, it certainly covers whatever elements have not yet been covered. Covering the rest of the elements (the set `CBar` in the notation of the proof) at cost `OPT` would mean covering each element at cost-effectiveness `OPT/|CBar|` by the definition of cost-effectiveness (aka price). As the optimal solution contains a set which covers all remaining elements, suppose we pick a set `S` from the optimal solution which covers at least one remaining element (`e_k` in lemma 2.3). Note that we are choosing the set with the best cost-effectiveness, so its cost-effectiveness must be at least as good as the average cost-effectiveness of the sets in the optimal solution of `OPT/|CBar|`.

The last part is that due to the definitions, `|CBar|=n-(k-1)=n-k+1` as `k-1` elements have already been covered and we are looking at covering element `k`. Therefore, the cost-effectiveness of `S` and therefore `price(e_k)` is bounded by `OPT/(n-k+1)`.